# event.target.id only questioning first option

Tags: javascript

I have code that uses event.target.id to evaluate what button is being pressed on the screen. But only the first one works. Even when I try to switch them around and still only my first button works.

```js
var multiplyer = 1
var carparts = 0;
document.getElementById("karpartz").innerHTML = carparts;

function onButtonClick(event) {
  if (event.target.id === "car") {
    carparts = carparts + multiplyer;
    document.getElementById("karpartz").innerHTML = carparts;
  } else if (event.target.id === "clickpower") {
    console.log("test (clickpower)")
  } else if (event.target.id === "idle") {
    console.log("test (idle scrapping)")
  }
}
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', onButtonClick);
```

```html
<button id="car">
  car goes here soon
</button>
<button id="clickpower">
  upgrade click power
</button>
<button id="idle">
  upgrade idle scrapping
</button>

<p id="karpartz"></p>

<html>

  <body>
    <h1>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("karpartz").innerHTML

      </script>
    </h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

I am not sure why this is happening. I think I might be doing something wrong or surpassing the limitations of JavaScript I am not sure. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) will only return at most 1 element, so right now you're only adding a click event listener to the first button. You can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select as many as possible. Then, once you have all of those buttons, you can loop through the [array-like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) object to add the click event listener to all buttons.

```js
function onButtonClick(event) {
  if (event.target.id === "car") {
    console.log("test (car)")
  } else if (event.target.id === "clickpower") {
    console.log("test (clickpower)")
  } else if (event.target.id === "idle") {
    console.log("test (idle scrapping)")
  }
}

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
for (const button of buttons) {
    button.addEventListener('click', onButtonClick);
}
```

```html
<button id="car">
  car goes here soon
</button>
<button id="clickpower">
  upgrade click power
</button>
<button id="idle">
  upgrade idle scrapping
</button>
```